# How To Make It So If An "input()" is a Certain Answer It Will Tell Me An Answer

Tags: python, input, printing

So i am working on something very basic (because I only started learning Python 3 days ago).

I Have decided to make a file that will collect information about a person and I wanted to make it so that when the User asks a certain question into an input it will find the data and display only that answer.

**The Code I am Working With Is Here:**

```
import os

x = input("What Is Your Name?: ")
y = input("How Old Are You?: ")
z = input("What Is Your Favourite Colour?: ")
os.system('CLS')

Info = [x, y, z]
for i in Info:
    print(i)
input('Press ENTER to move on')
os.system('CLS')

input("What Are You Looking For?")

if input == "Age":
    print(y)

input('Press ENTER to exit')
```

**(But The Main Bit You Want To Focus On Is:**

```
input("What Are You Looking For?")

if input == "Age":
    print(y)
```

The problem is when we get to that part of the program it will only do the

```
input()
```

Part, after that it closes.

I was wondering if there was anyway i could make it do this:

**What Are You Looking For?**

**Age**

**(Then it would print z)**

Sorry if this is impossible to understand I have no idea how to explain the problem.

Any help is good help, Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`input()` returns whatever the user entered as a string.

```
answer = input("What Are You Looking For?")

if answer == "Age":
    print(y)
```